# Give IBAction priority instead of segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm using storyboard, and in my storyboard I got a button which I connected with another view controller. So when you click the button, the other view controller shows up. I connected this using an Action Segue - Push in the storyboard. I also connected the button with an IBAction property. The problem is when I click the button it first goes to the view controller that its connected to, and after that it executes the IBAction function. How can I change this order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change that order. There are two things that you can do.

First: 
Use the segue only. 
Overwrite `prepareForSegue:` and place your code there. If there is more than one segure from that view controller then you can distinguish within `prepareForSegue:` which one is currently being performed. For that you should provide them with unique names/segue IDs.

Second: 
Use the IBAction only. 
Within the IBAction method, at its very end, call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. Again, for that you will have to name all your segues with unique segue IDs.

Comment: I've tried that but I got this error: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MainScrollViewController: 0x86f9070>.

Comment: You have to either delete the segue, or delete the IBAction connection.  If you delete the IBAction connection, implement `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:sender`

Comment: I want to use the IBAction, so how do I connect this with the segue?

Comment: Yes, you have to either delete the segue (attached to the button) or the IBAction. But you can still have the segue from the view controller itself so that it does exist ith its name and properties (push etc) and leads to the view controller you want.

Comment: Alternatively you can load the target view controller from the storyboard and push it to the navigation stack as you would do when you don't use storyboard. But it works with the segue. It is just that the segure must not be connected to the button if you want to use the IBAction.

Comment: I've tried it with prepareForSegue. In that function I did what needs to be done before the segue, but it still does the segue first...

Comment: If I try it with NSLog, it works but I'm using SVProgressHUD and when I push the button I want to show the ProgressHUD and when the view controller is finished loading I want to dismiss the ProgressHUD. The problem is I click the button -> view controller shows up -> ProgressHUD shows up

Answer (score 0):

The question to ask yourself is, why are you using both? Pick one and stick with it IMO.

If you want to perform some actions when the segue happens you should implement

[`prepareForSegue:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW84)

**Update to address comment**

> I actually don't know how I can do it in code, how can I load a ViewController that is on my storyboard without using the Action Segue Push?

The easiest way that I've found is in your Storyboard you can set an identifier for the view controller.

[image]

Notice **Storyboard ID** is set to MyViewController

Now in your IBAction method you can do the following.

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I actually don't know how I can do it in code, how can I load a ViewController that is on my storyboard without using the Action Segue Push?

Comment: Updated to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by chaining the IBAction from my segue. I find this approach the most useful as I can have a "save" action without a segue (chain a button to the IBAction, sometimes useful), and also use a segue for dismissing the view controller when necessary.

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
 /* Do some Save stuff */
}
```

Then in my prepareForSegue:sender:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"save"])
    {
        [self save:sender];
    }
}
```

Link up your non-segue buttons to the IBAction, and segue your unwind or other such buttons with an identifier as "save". Magic.